# Error in load Namespace, object 'vI' not found with package AnnotationDbi

Tags: r, install.packages

```
install.packages("AnnotationDbi", dependencies=TRUE, type="win.binary")
```

Getting the same error when I try to load in library:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘AnnotationDbi’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
> object 'vI' not found

I tried multiple things, I am getting the same error every time.

Answer (score 0):

`AnnotationDbi` probably needs to be installed with the [Bioconductor](http://www.bioconductor.org/install/) library rather than from CRAN:

```
install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("AnnotationDbi")
```

See details in the [documentation](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/AnnotationDbi.html), hope this helps.